# Pass multiple tuple to python SQLite command

Tags: python, sqlite, tuples

I'm trying to pass multiple tuple to placeholders in SQLite.
Example I got 2 tuple like below:

```
tup_A = (1, 2, 3, 4)
tup_B = (5, 6, 7, 8)
```

The SQL command like:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM abc WHERE col_A IN (?,?,?,?) AND NOT IN (?,?,?,?) ORDER BY col_A;'
```

So I have tried the executor:

```
results = executor(sql, (tup_A,tup_B))
```

and

```
results = executor(sql, tup_A + tup_B)
```

but it result in

```
OperationalError('near "IN": syntax error',)
```

I have tried successfully run command with one parameter:

```
    sql = 'SELECT * FROM abc WHERE col_A IN (?,?,?,?) ORDER BY col_A;'
    results = executor(sql, tup_A)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Pay attention to the error you're getting. You have a problem with your query syntax.

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) might help realize what the issue is.

Comment: thanks Shawn, I realized that I missed the col_a before NOT IN clause

Comment: You don't need `AND col_A NOT IN (?,?,?,?)` as the first part of the query filters out those records any way.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I missed the col_a before NOT IN clause, and this command work:

```
results = executor(sql, tup_A + tup_B)
```